# how can i load the word list into a 3x3 grid?

Tags: python, grid

```
import random
weird_list=open("f:\\weird_list.txt", "r")    
wordlist=weird_list.read()                     #opens, reads and closes the    text file.
weird_list.close()                           
wordlist=wordlist.split()
```

This code opens a file for input that contains 10 words.

```
random1 = random.choice(wordlist)        #displays the random words one by one until it opens 9 out of 10.    
wordlist.remove(random1)            

random2 = random.choice(wordlist)  #it does this by removing the word from the file.
wordlist.remove(random2)

random3 = random.choice(wordlist)
wordlist.remove(random3)

random4 = random.choice(wordlist)
wordlist.remove(random4)

random5 = random.choice(wordlist)
wordlist.remove(random5)

random6 = random.choice(wordlist)
wordlist.remove(random6)

random7 = random.choice(wordlist)
wordlist.remove(random7)

random8 = random.choice(wordlist)
wordlist.remove(random8)

random9 = random.choice(wordlist)
wordlist.remove(random9)
```

The words that are in the file are: NIGHT,SMOKE,GHOST,TOOTH,ABOUT,CAMEL,BROWN,FUNNY,CHAIR,PRICE

```
print ("Let's play guess the word \n I have a random list of words \n the computer will select randomly from the word list leaving you one remaining word to guess.")
```

It explains the game rules to the player.

```
print ("I will give you the following words, you then tell me the missing   word: \n", random1, random2, random3, random4, random5, random6, random7,   random8,   random9,)
```

This prints (displays) the words.

```
wordsstr =''.join(str(x) for x in wordlist)

weirdguess = input("what is the missing word?: ")

while weirdguess != wordsstr: 
   weirdguess == input ("try another word: ")


print ("You guessed correctly. Game over") #ends the while loop
```

Comment: I think you will need to explain what you mean by a 3x3 grid. What data structure are you using? How will the 3x3 grid be used?

Answer (score 0):

You can use list-comprehension:

```
import random
weird_list=open("f:\\weird_list.txt", "r")    
wordlist=weird_list.read() #opens, reads, and closes the text file.
weird_list.close()                           
wordlist=wordlist.split()
random.shuffle(wordlist)
wordstr = wordlist[0]
wordlist = wordlist[1:]
print("\n".join(" ".join(wordlist[x:x+3]) for x in range(0, len(wordlist), 3)))

print("Correct answer: %s" % wordstr)
```

Output:

```
NIGHT CHAIR BROWN
PRICE SMOKE GHOST
CAMEL TOOTH ABOUT
Correct answer: FUNNY
```

Notice, I also changed your randomizer.  `random.shuffle()` is much easier than shuffling it yourself with `random.choice()`.